# VBA copy columns from multiple files knowing keyword

Tags: excel, vba, loops, copy, keyword

I am new to VBA and I would like to create a code which exports range D10:D33 from Sheet1 from a range of files in a specific folder and pastes it to the next available column in the same workbook in Sheet2.

The names of files change depending on date ex. YYYYMMDD_output. There are many dates in the folder such as 20200609, 20200610, and I am interested in 20200608.

The code below searches the keyword '20200608' to find the files and it is supposed to paste data into Active workbook in Sheet2. I have trouble with looping through the changing name file.

Would appreciate your help.

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub copycolumns()

 Dim myPath As String
 Dim myFile As String
 Dim MyName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim wsl As Worksheet
 Dim r As Long

 myPath = "C:\Users\halo\Desktop\Backup"
 myFile = Dir(myPath & "20200608*.xlsx", vbNormal)

 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

 MyName = Dir(myPath & myFile)
 r = ws.Range("E" & Columns.Count).End(xlRight).Column + 1
 Do While MyName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open myPath & MyName
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws1.Range("D10:D33").Copy
    ws.Range(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues

  Workbooks(MyName).Close SaveChanges:=False
  MyName = Dir

  Loop


 End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Comment: Is this part of your question (**"pastes it to the next available column in the same workbook in Sheet2"**) true? Your code shows something different...

Comment: I don't think `r` is being picked out right `r = ws.Range("E" & Columns.Count).End(xlRight).Column + 1`

Comment: Move this line `r = ws.Range("E" & Columns.Count).End(xlRight).Column + 1` inside the loop, please and transfom it in `r = ws.cells(1,  Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1`.

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes the question is right but I am not sure how to write the code for that

Comment: It is not a matter of code, I am afraid... Do you want to paste it **in the same workbook**, just open, like you said, or in a different one (`ws` worksheet which was defined before the other document has been opened...). I prepared an answer which copy it in the active sheet (`ws`)...

Answer (score 0):

Try the next modification, please:

Transform the way of `r` calculation in:

```
r = ws.Cells(1,  Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
```

and move the line inside the loop

Then, transform this line

```
ws.Range(r, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

in

```
ws.Cells(1, r).PasteSpecial xlValues
```

In fact, since you need only values (not any format) it is better to use an array. It is simpler to post whole your (adapted) code. Try the next one, please:

```
Sub copycolumns_Bis()

 Dim myPath As String
 Dim myFile As String
 Dim MyName As String
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim wsl As Worksheet
 Dim r As Long

 myPath = "C:\Users\halo\Desktop\Backup"
 myFile = Dir(myPath & "20200608*.xlsx", vbNormal)

 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

 MyName = Dir(myPath & myFile)

 Do While MyName <> ""
    Dim arrCopy As Variant
    r = ws.Cells(1 & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
    Workbooks.Open myPath & MyName
    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    arrCopy = ws1.Range("D10:D33").Value
    ws.Range(1, r).Resize(UBound(arrCopy, 1), UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy
    Workbooks(MyName).Close SaveChanges:=False

    MyName = Dir
  Loop
 End Sub
```

The code will work with more columns to be copied, too. I mean, range to be copied may include more columns.

Comment: Hi @FaneDuru, thank you for your reply. I get a run-time '1004' error  Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet failed in line  **ws.Range(r, Columns.Count).Resize(UBound(arrCopy, 1), UBound(arrCopy, 2)).Value = arrCopy**

Comment: @mromankim: I updated the code. Please, check it now. Do no forget to refresh the page  (this one) in order to use the updated code...